# error for returning subject and return type as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new bee for angular trying to learn Angular concepts,
what I'm tring to do is Observable as return type and returning subject, where IEvent is a Interface defined as below,

```
export interface IEvent{
    id: number
    name:string 
    date: Date
    time: string
    price: number
    imageUrl:string
    location?:{
        address:string
        city:string
        country:string
    }
    onlineurl?:string
    sessions:ISession[]

}
```

In another class I have code something like this,

```
 const EVENTS : IEvent[] = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Angular Connect',
          date: new Date('9/26/2036'),
          time: '10:00 am',
          price: 599.99,
          imageUrl: '/app/assets/images/angularconnect-shield.png',
          location: {
            address: '1057 DT',
            city: 'London',
            country: 'England'
          },
          ......
     }
```

and in the same class there is one method as getEvents() as below,

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService{
    getEvents(): Observable<IEvent[]>{
      let subject = new Subject<IEvent[]>()
      setTimeout(() => { subject.next(EVENTS); subject.complete();},100)

      return subject
    }
```

At "return subject" statement , getting an compiler error as, Type Observable is not assignable to type Observable,
Type IEvent[] is not assignable to type 'R'.

I don't understand why this compilation time error, as I know Subject extends Observable so returning the subject make sense to me.
what I'm doing wrong by returning a subject and and return type as Observable.

Comment: Try RxJS 5.4.2 or later. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593

Comment: @cartant Thanks for quick reply.. So now I have changed the version for rxjs in package.json then do I have to anything to get the latest version or npm start will handle it?

Comment: After changing the version of the dependency in the `package.json`, you need to re-install/upgrade the `rxjs` module. The process will differ depending upon whether you are using npm 4 or 5 or yarn. You can either delete `node_modules` and re-install everything or read up on whichever tool you are using and learn how to perform a single module upgrade.

Comment: Yes it resolved the problem, thanks cartant